# ¿Por qué el método get me retorna más de un resultado?

Tags: python, django

Quiero saber si existe un nombre X en la base de datos, de no existir lo creo o de lo contrario le modifico sus datos.

Con el método `get` pido que me lo devuelva y me lanza el siguiente error:

`get() returned more than one Mostrar_Resultado -- it returned 2!`

Aquí esta el código:

```
def AnalizarAction(listarepo,listday):
    estado=''
    for reporte in listarepo:
        w = reporte.action.split(' ')
        if 'change' in reporte.action:
            estado = w[-1]
        elif 'assigned' in reporte.action:
            estado = w[-1]

        else:
            estado = '%s %s' % (w[-2], w[-1])
            estado = estado.replace("'", "")


        try:
            resultado = Mostrar_Resultado.objects.get(nombre=reporte.user)
            print('resultado-before-save', resultado)
            resultado.alarma_asignada = 2

            print('alarma asignada', resultado.alarma_asignada)
            alm_asignadar = resultado.alarma_asignada + 1
            print(type(alm_asignadar))
            print('alarma-asignada-incr', alm_asignadar)
            datos_devueltos = getParametrosByEstado(alm_asignadar, reporte, estado,listday)
            print('dict', datos_devueltos)
            print('type', type(datos_devueltos))
            # Solo aki se modifica
            if type(datos_devueltos) == dict:
                print('dict-dentro-if', datos_devueltos)
                resultado.alarma_asignada = alm_asignadar
                resultado.fraude = datos_devueltos['fraude']
                resultado.disponible_fr = datos_devueltos['disponible_fra']
                resultado.alm_inv = datos_devueltos['alm_inv']
                resultado.bajo_inv_cierre = datos_devueltos['bajo_inv_cierre']
                resultado.por_ciento_fr = datos_devueltos['por_ciento_fr']
                resultado.uso_sistema = datos_devueltos['uso_sistema']
                resultado.save()
                print('resultado-after-save', resultado)
        except Mostrar_Resultado.DoesNotExist:
            print "NO EXISTE... crear"
            alm_asignadar = 1
            datos_devueltos = getParametrosByEstado(alm_asignadar, reporte, estado,listday)

            if type(datos_devueltos) == dict:
                fraude = datos_devueltos['fraude']
                no_fraude = datos_devueltos['no_fraude']
                disponible_fra = datos_devueltos['disponible_fra']
                alm_inv = datos_devueltos['alm_inv']
                bajo_inv_cierre = datos_devueltos['bajo_inv_cierre']
                por_ciento_fr = datos_devueltos['por_ciento_fr']
                uso_sistema = datos_devueltos['uso_sistema']
                llaver = reporte
                print('Este es la llave', llaver)
                nombrer = reporte.user
                fechar = reporte.day
                CrearResultado(llaver, nombrer, fechar, alm_asignadar, fraude, no_fraude, disponible_fra, alm_inv,
                               bajo_inv_cierre, por_ciento_fr, uso_sistema)
```

Este es mi modelo:

```
class Mostrar_Resultado(models.Model): 
    llave = models.ForeignKey(Reportes)     
    nombre = models.CharField(null=False,max_length=50) 
    fecha = models.CharField(null=False,max_length=50) 
    alarma_asignada = models.IntegerField(null=False) 
    fraude = models.IntegerField(null=False) 
    no_fraude = models.IntegerField(null=False) 
    disponible_fr = models.IntegerField(null=False) 
    alm_inv = models.IntegerField(null=False) 
    bajo_inv_cierre = models.IntegerField(null=False) 
    por_ciento_fr = models.IntegerField(default=0) 
    uso_sistema = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Comment: El método `get` se usa para obtener un resultado único, si el campo `nombre` en tu modelo no es único, es decir, existe más de un registro en la base de datos con la condición `nombre=request.user`, entonces se produce el error.

Comment: esta es mi class model: donde esta el atributo nombre es unico

Comment: class Mostrar_Resultado(models.Model):
    llave=models.ForeignKey(Reportes)
    nombre=models.CharField(null=False,max_length=50)
    fecha=models.CharField(null=False,max_length=50)
    alarma_asignada=models.IntegerField(null=False)
    fraude=models.IntegerField(null=False)
    no_fraude=models.IntegerField(null=False)
    disponible_fr=models.IntegerField(null=False)
    alm_inv=models.IntegerField(null=False)
    bajo_inv_cierre=models.IntegerField(null=False)
    por_ciento_fr=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    uso_sistema=models.IntegerField(default=0)

Comment: El atributo `nombre` no es único, simplemente acepta nulos. Para hacerlo único tienes que tener `unique=True`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ¿Por qué el método get me retorna más de un resultado?

Si le das un vistazo a [`MultipleObjectsReturned`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/exceptions/#multipleobjectsreturned) en la documentación vas a poder ver que este error ocurre cuando el query espera recibir solo un resultado (mediante el método `get`) pero múltiples objetos o registros son retornados por el query.

Según tu modelo, es posible tener varios registros con el mismo `nombre`. Si quisieras mantener tu código usando excepciones, podrías actualizarlo para que se vea más o menos así:

```
def AnalizarAction(listarepo,listday):
    # ...
    for reporte in listarepo:
        try:
            resultado = Mostrar_Resultado.objects.get(nombre=reporte.user)
            # ...
        except Mostrar_Resultado.DoesNotExist:
            # ...
        except Mostrar_Resultado.MultipleObjectsReturned:
            # Iterar todos los resultados y actualizarlos
```

Sin embargo, lo que te recomendaría es que en vez de capturar las excepciones, consultes la existencia del resultado. Algo como esto:

```
def AnalizarAction(listarepo,listday):
    # ...
    for reporte in listarepo:
        resultados = Mostrar_Resultado.objects.filter(nombre=reporte.user)
        if resultados.exists():
            # Hay registros, actualizarlos
        else:
            # No hay registros, crearlo
```

En vez de usar el método `get` lo he cambiado por un `filter` ya que este último no dará problemas si existe más de un registro con el mismo `nombre`. También, estoy aprovechando el método [`exists`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists) para preguntar si el query tiene algún resultado.